# Install haproxy 1.5 without telling apt specific version

Tags: apt, aptitude, haproxy

In Ubuntu 14.04 installing haproxy through

```
apt-get install haproxy
```

installs haproxy 1.4, while 1.5 is in the repository.

How can I install haproxy 1.5 (or the newest) **without** resorting to specific versions?

For example,

```
    apt-get install haproxy=1.5.3-1~ubuntu1
```

Comment: The latest version available for 14.04 in the main repo is `1.4.24-2`..are you using PPA ?

Comment: it's in backports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
    apt-get -t trusty-backports install haproxy
```

Comment: ...bearing in mind the risks (however small) associated with backports. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#Stability_of_Backports